# Open file dialogbox in vue composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am trying to open the Select file dialog box when clicking on the button, It is possible using `this.$refs.fileInput.click()` in VUE, but this is not working in composition API.

Here is the code for reference: https://codepen.io/imjatin/pen/zYvGpBq

Script

```js
    const { ref, computed, watch, onMounted, context } = vueCompositionApi;

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    Vue.use(vueCompositionApi.default);

    new Vue({
      setup(context) {    
        const fileInput = ref(null);
        const trigger = () => {
          fileInput.click()
        }; 

        // lifecycle
        onMounted(() => {     
        });
        // expose bindings on render context
        return {
          trigger,fileInput 
        };
      }
    }).$mount('#app');
```

Template

```html
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <div @click="trigger" class="trigger">Click me</div>
      <input type="file" ref="fileInput"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access it using `context.refs.fileInput.click();`?

Don't forget that it's `setup(props, context)` and not `setup(context)`.

Try my edit here: https://codepen.io/ziszo/pen/oNxbvWW

Good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm working in Vue 3 CLI and have tried several different recommendations and found the following to be the most reliable.

```
<template>  
    <input class="btnFileLoad" type="file" ref="oFileHandler" @change="LoadMethod($event)" />
    <button class="btn" @click="fileLoad">Load</button>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from "vue";
export default{
    setup(){
         const hiddenFileElement = ref({})
         return {hiddenFileElement }
    }
    methods:{
        fileLoad() {
        this.hiddenFileElement = this.$refs.oFileHandler;
        this.hiddenFileElement.click();
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.btn{ background-color:blue; color:white; }
.btnFileLoad{ display:none }
</style>
```

I also discovered in Chrome that if the call from the button element to the hidden file handler takes to long, an error message that reads "File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation." is displayed in the source view.  By defining the hiddenFileElement in setup the problem went away.

Comment: `methods` is part of the Options API, not Composition API.